# Android ACTION_SEND event: "messaging failed to upload attachment"

Tags: android

I'm trying to implement a share button that captures a screenshot and shares it through the standard Android interface. I'm able to create the screenshot (and I can see it when I browse the SD card), but when I try to send it, the messages app gives the error: "messaging failed to upload attachment."

### My code

```
File imageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "inPin");
if(!imageDir.exists()) { imageDir.mkdirs(); }
File closeupImageFile = new File(imageDir, "closeup.png");
File overviewImageFile = new File(imageDir, "overview.png");

View mapView = findViewById(R.id.floor_map);
saveScreenshotToFile(mapView, closeupImageFile);

ArrayList<Uri> imageUris = new ArrayList<Uri>();
imageUris.add(Uri.fromFile(closeupImageFile));

String message = String.format("I'm on %s %s", building.name, getCurrentFloor().name);

Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);
sendIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageUris);
sendIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
sendIntent.setType("image/*");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, "Share via"));
```

### The saveScreenshotToFile method

```
private static void saveScreenshotToFile(View view, File saveFile) throws IOException {
    view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    view.buildDrawingCache(true);
    Bitmap bitmap = view.getDrawingCache();
    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(saveFile);
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
    out.close();
}
```

I'm using Android Marshmallow, API level 23, on the emulator—I don't know if this makes a difference, but I was able to share using other apps on the emulator and it worked fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are sending File URIs, with which `Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION` does not apply and should not be used, as explained in [this video](https://youtu.be/h9TunRURWNU?list=PLWz5rJ2EKKc9ULCmS36PAYi2__VMx3vjs&t=123) and its [accompanying blog post](https://medium.com/@ianhlake/sharing-content-between-android-apps-2e6db9d1368b#ad2c). Other apps would need the storage permission to access your files.

From the blog post:

> Instead, you can use URI permissions to grant other apps access to specific Uris. While URI permissions don’t work on `file://` URIs as is generated by `Uri.fromFile()`, they do work on Uris associated with [Content Providers](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html). Rather than implement your own just for this, you can and should use **[FileProvider](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html)** as explained in the [File Sharing Training](http://developer.android.com/training/secure-file-sharing/index.html).

Comment: Switched to using FileProvider and it works perfectly! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you have to send MMS with any Image using Intent then use this code.

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND); 
sendIntent.setClassName("com.android.mms", "com.android.mms.ui.ComposeMessageActivity");
sendIntent.putExtra("sms_body", "some text"); 
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file:///sdcard/image_4.png"));
sendIntent.setType("image/png");
startActivity(sendIntent);
```

OR

If you have to send MMS with Audio or Video file using Intent then use this.

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND); 
sendIntent.setClassName("com.android.mms", "com.android.mms.ui.ComposeMessageActivity");
sendIntent.putExtra("address", "1213123123");
sendIntent.putExtra("sms_body", "if you are sending text");   
final File file1 = new File(mFileName);
if(file1.exists()){
  System.out.println("file is exist");
}
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file1);
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
sendIntent.setType("video/*");
startActivity(sendIntent);
```